# Trying to create a module that counts non-letter symbols in C

Tags: c, string, module

I need the user to input a string, read it, convert it to lower case, then count the instances of the letters and the non-letters.

I've already got modules to read it, convert it to lower case, and then count the instances of the letters; but I can't figure out how to check for the things like commas, and percentage signs, without resorting to a massive case statement, which I've been told would get me a bad grade.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you count letter symbols? The rest is non-letter. Post your piece of code for counting, noone will write full solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check ranges of ascii values (see http://www.asciitable.com/ ).  As you can see, ranges of dec 48-57 are numbers and dec 65-90 and dec 97-122 are upper case and lower case letters, respectively. That gives you 3 ranges to check.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do this is checking if the current character is out of the range `'A'` to `'Z'` and `'a'` to `'z'`.

```
if( ( (ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z') ) || ( (ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z') ) )
{
    //Received char ch is one of characters 'A to Z' or 'a to z'
}
else
{
    //Its something else
}
```